# looking for an opensoure authenciation releated project to learn

Tags: java, authentication, rbac

I have three  years's expeirence of java develping.

Now I am working with an system which is related to the ahthenciation. I am not good at this.

So I wonder if there is any opensoure project I can read and learn someting from which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Fortress, it is released under BSD open source license:  http://iamfortress.org/